# How to access GridView ButtonField Control IDs?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am dealing with a ButtonField column in a GridView, whose RowCommand handler is not triggered in the following lifecycle.

This is a common issue around the web and - among others - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324003/how-can-i-re-instantiate-dynamic-asp-net-user-controls-without-using-a-database) SO post helped me understand, that it is caused by differences in the IDs of controls in the control trees of the former and the new instance of the webpage.

What remains: in a Button_Click EventHandler, before the instance is about to be destroyed, I need to save (into Session) the IDs of a ButtonField in a gridView, that is passed to the EventHandler like so:

```
    protected GridView Create_GV(DataTable BetTable)
    {
        GridView GV = new GridView
        {
            DataSource = BetTable,
            HorizontalAlign = System.Web.UI.WebControls.HorizontalAlign.Center
        };

        GV.Columns.Add(new ButtonField { Text = "+", CommandName = "Select" });
        GV.DataBind();
        GV.RowCommand += GV_RowCommand;

        //cycle the columns so that the buttonfield is the last one

        int ncol = BetTable.Columns.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < ncol; i++) GV.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text = GV.HeaderRow.Cells[i + 1].Text;
        GV.HeaderRow.Cells[ncol].Text = "Přidat";
        
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GV.Rows)
        {
            List<TableCell> columns = new List<TableCell>();
            foreach (DataControlField column in GV.Columns)
            {
                TableCell cell = row.Cells[0];
                row.Cells.Remove(cell);
                columns.Add(cell);
            }
            row.Cells.AddRange(columns.ToArray());
        }
        return GV;
    }
```

Then in the Page_Init I need to recreate the GridView as it was and reset the IDs of the ButtonField to the original value(s).

I am intentionally saying IDs of the ButtonField, because I don't even know, if there's one or more - couldn't find out.

**How to get/set GridView's ButtonField ID(s)?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things you need to change in your code to make things work. 
Kudos for trying. You are almost there.

1. Your row command event handler should be added before the databind
   call.
2. Move the cycling code for the buttonfield to
   the row created event
3. Only create one instance of the grid by putting an existence 
   check when initializing your datagridview.

I created a sample working solution using an ArrayList. Download the sample [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c7azydd1fapx7iy/WebApplication3.zip?dl=0)
and modify it to suit your needs.

**Aspx.cs**

```
 using System.Collections.Generic;

 namespace WebApplication3
            {
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    GridView GV = null;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //Dummy datasource
        ArrayList names = new ArrayList() { };
        names.Add(new Person { Age = 29, Name = "Abide", Surname = "Masaraure" });
        names.Add(new Person { Age = 28, Name = "Lopi", Surname = "Sewa" });
        Create_GV(names);


    }

    protected void Create_GV(ArrayList BetTable)
    {
        if (GV == null)
        {
            GV = new GridView
            {
                DataSource = BetTable,
                HorizontalAlign = System.Web.UI.WebControls.HorizontalAlign.Center
            };

            GV.DataSource = BetTable;
            GV.Columns.Add(new ButtonField { Text = "+", CommandName = "Select" });

            GV.RowCommand += GV_RowCommand;
            GV.RowCreated += GV_RowCreated;

            GV.DataBind();
            GV.HeaderRow.Cells[BetTable.Capacity-1].Text = "Přidat";
            form1.Controls.Add(GV);
        }
    }



    protected void GV_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
          //this will fire
    }


    protected void GV_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        GridViewRow row = e.Row;
        // Intitialize TableCell list
        List<TableCell> columns = new List<TableCell>();
        foreach (DataControlField column in GV.Columns)
        {
            //Get the first Cell /Column
            TableCell cell = row.Cells[0];
            // Then Remove it after
            row.Cells.Remove(cell);
            //And Add it to the List Collections
            columns.Add(cell);
        }

        // Add cells
        row.Cells.AddRange(columns.ToArray());
    }


      }

class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
        }
```

**Markup**

```
<html>
    <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
   </head>
      <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>


    </div>
    </form>
   </body>
    </html>
```

You might also consider placing an empty grid view on your mark-up.This will save you some effort in trying to create the grid manually and it will be much easier for you to wire your event handlers.